Angular CacheStorage not storing Response as expected when converted from HttpResponse
In Angular 15 I'm implementing Client-Side caching through the CacheStorage interface.
I convert back and forth between HttpResponse and fetch interface's Response type when storing responses in CacheStorage.
When I retrieve a Response from CacheStorage, as it always stores the body as a ReadableStream, and the stream is always empty.
I had an issue with retrieving and storing responses and followed this related issue:
Trying to Cache HttpClient Response but getting 'HttpResponse<Blob>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Response'
First, I convert the HttpResponse from Angular to a fetch Response by
const responseToCache = new Response(response.body, {
      status: response.status,
      statusText: response.statusText,
});

Since CacheStorage requires fetch's Response type.
Then, I retrieve the cached response through
const cachedResponse = await caches.open(this.cacheName).then((cache) => cache.match(url.urlWithParams));

But whenever the cachedResponse comes back, the body is always as a ReadableStream
Response object from CacheStorage
I have tried converting the ReadableStream back into an Object and string, but it is always empty.
Not sure what else to try, thank you!
